# Magento 1 Trigger Customer Segment Data Refresh

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-segmentation

On completion of an order, I would like to trigger a refresh of a certain Customer Segment. What method could I call to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$segment = Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_customersegment/segment')->load($segment_id);
$segment->matchCustomers();
```

Comment: Hi, please accept your own answer if this question is resolved. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/ This platform is still in Beta and we need an answer rate of 80%.